# How to manipulate prediction response from Google AutoML in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-cloud-automl

I have successfully trained a Google AutoML Natural Language model to do multi-label categorization of text using custom labels.

I'm also able to use the python function generated by the trained dataset to generate predictions on text contained in a Pandas DataFrame in a Jupyter Notebook.

**However I'm not sure how to use the result** and especially manipulate it so that it's useful to me.

Here's what my code looks like currently:

```
r = #api call to get text
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(r.text), usecols=['text_to_predict'])
df['Category_Predicted'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_prediction(row.review, 'xxx', 'xxxx')
```

The output of df['Category_Predicted'].head() is

```
0    payload {\n  classification {\n    score: 0.61...
Name: Category_Predicted, dtype: object
```

And a simple (more readable) print of one prediction returns

```
payload {
  classification {
    score: 0.6122230887413025
  }
  display_name: "Shopping"
}
payload {
  classification {
    score: 0.608892023563385
  }
  display_name: "Search"
}
payload {
  classification {
    score: 0.38840705156326294
  }
  display_name: "Usability"
}
payload {
  classification {
    score: 0.2736874222755432
  }
  display_name: "Stability"
}
payload {
  classification {
    score: 0.011237740516662598
  }
  display_name: "Profile"
}
#......................(continues on for all categories)
```

Now, my primary objective would be for df['Category_Predicted'] to be a field where the topmost (most relevant) categories are comma separated in a simple list. The example above would be

```
Shopping, Search, Usability
```

(depending how far you want you want to keep labels based on the score)

So I have several some on my hands:

- How to access with python this field to get the category and it's related score?
- How to manipulate it to create a single string?

Thanks!

***EDIT***

***As requested in comments, below some examples representing 2 records in my dataframe*** with (non-complete) payload where in the desired result I have filtered results with score > 0.3. Due to the large text fields I had to use a... "custom" solution for presentation instead of ascii tables

***ROW 1 - TEXT TO PREDICT***

*Great app so far. Just a pity that you can not look in the old app what you still had in your shopping or what your favorites were. This fact is simply gone. Plus that you now have to enter everything in the new one !!!*

***ROW 1 - PREDICTION OUTPUT***

```
payload {
  classification {
    score: 0.6122230887413025
  }
  display_name: "Shopping"
}
payload {
  classification {
    score: 0.608892023563385
  }
  display_name: "Search"
}
payload {
  classification {
    score: 0.38840705156326294
  }
  display_name: "Usability"
}
payload {
  classification {
    score: 0.2736874222755432
  }
  display_name: "Stability"
}
```

***ROW 1 - DESIRED OUTPUT***

Shopping, Search, Usability

***ROW 2 - TEXT TO PREDICT***

*2nd time you make us the joke of a new app worse than the 1st. How long before raising the level with this one? Not intuitive at all, not so clear ... In short not at the level of the previous one*

***ROW 2 - PREDICTION OUTPUT***

```
payload {
  classification {
    score: 0.9011210203170776
  }
  display_name: "Usability"
}
payload {
  classification {
    score: 0.8007309436798096
  }
  display_name: "Shopping"
}
payload {
  classification {
    score: 0.5114057660102844
  }
  display_name: "Stability"
}
payload {
  classification {
    score: 0.226901113986969
  }
  display_name: "Search"
}
```

***ROW 2 - DESIRED OUTPUT***

Usability, Shopping, Stability

Comment: How do *you* define "most relevant"?  Is it something other than the score?

Comment: Is there a fixed list of category names, or do these change from row to row?

Comment: Changed the wording from "depending how you define most relevant" to "depending how far you want to keep labels based on the score"
Ofc I want to use the score as relevancy, but I'm still not sure where to draw the line for a finite list. But that's a question that goes back to myself :D



The total list of categories is fixed (which is the set I trained with. they all appear in the prediction even if they have score 0) but only a few will be relevant in each record. Let's say from 1 to any that scores 0.3 or above

Comment: Okay, I see.  Now can you post a small sample version of your dataframe in code, so it can be copied and pasted?  It doesn't have to include all the payloads or rows - just a couple rows and 3 or 4 payloads per row would probably work.  That way I (and other potential answerers) can easily test whether our solutions work.

Comment: I feel a bit stupid but in the examples I gave I always treated the prediction response from Google AutoML as a string. However I just found out that it's an object described here https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.automl.v1beta1#predictresponse ....

Comment: Don't feel stupid - I've often found that as I try to specify a question well, the answer becomes clear to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's bad to answer my own question, but I figured if somebody looks for the same problem, they might find a solution.

As google.cloud.automl_v1beta1 defines it, the return value of method get_prediction is an object of type PredictResponse ( https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.automl.v1beta1#predictresponse )

Using the documentation and available structure of such object I found this code does the trick

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    pred = get_prediction(row['review'], GCP_PROJ, AUTOML_DS)
    filteredCategories = filter(filterPrediction, pred.payload)
    df.at[index,'Predicted_Categories'] = ",".join([str(categ.display_name) for categ in filteredCategories])
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that , you wanted most relevant category as per prediciton score. I placed your prediction string output in a text file e.g `out.txt`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('out.txt',
             header=None,
             delim_whitespace=True,
             names=['data'])
score = df.loc['score:']['data'].values
category = df.loc['display_name:']['data'].values
score_category = zip(score,category)
for category in sorted(list(score_category), key=lambda x:x[0], reverse=True):
    print(category[1], end=", ")
```

For above shared prediction result and got the results:-

```
Shopping, Search, Usability, Stability, Profile,
```